# I want to get the price linked to an specific product

Tags: c#

So i have this code, my problem is that i want to find with the item's code (codigo) what is the product and price (precio).

Something as if i put ´01´ it will show me on screen what product it is and how much it cost  and then sum it to the shopping list

The other problem is that it cant have modular programming (yeah i know..) cause is for a friend and his techer is kinda jackass. But if is necesary, do it modular and i will try to change it later.

I just need to find out how to obtain name of product and price with the item code

I apologize cause the code is on spanish

```
namespace CodigoSupermercado
{
    public struct Lista
    {
        public double precio;
        public string producto;
        public int codigo;
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Lista[] v;
            v = new Lista[10];
            v[0].producto = "aceite mezcla";    v[0].precio = 6.00;    v[0].codigo = 01;
            v[1].producto = "arroz";            v[1].precio = 2.00;    v[1].codigo = 02;
            v[2].producto = "azucar";           v[2].precio = 3.00;    v[2].codigo = 03;
            v[3].producto = "caraotas";         v[3].precio = 6.00;    v[3].codigo = 04;
            v[4].producto = "carne de primera"; v[4].precio = 15.00;   v[4].codigo = 05;
            v[5].producto = "carne de segunda"; v[5].precio = 10.00;   v[5].codigo = 06;
            v[6].producto = "harina precocida"; v[6].precio = 2.50;    v[6].codigo = 07;
            v[7].producto = "leche en polvo";   v[7].precio = 12.00;   v[7].codigo = 08;
            v[8].producto = "pasta";            v[8].precio = 2.50;    v[8].codigo = 09;
            v[9].producto = "pollo entero";     v[9].precio = 10.00;   v[9].codigo = 10;

            Console.WriteLine("Bienvenido al Sistema de Compras");
            Console.WriteLine("ELiga los productos a facturar: ");
            Console.WriteLine("| Cod |      Producto    |     Precio     |");
            Console.WriteLine("|  01 |Aceite Mezcla     |      6.00      |");
            Console.WriteLine("|  02 |Arroz             |      2.00      |");
            Console.WriteLine("|  03 |Azucar            |      3.00      |");
            Console.WriteLine("|  04 |Caraotas          |      6.00      |");
            Console.WriteLine("|  05 |Carne de Primera  |     15.00      |");
            Console.WriteLine("|  06 |Carne de Segunda  |     10.00      |");
            Console.WriteLine("|  07 |Harina Precocida  |      2.50      |");
            Console.WriteLine("|  08 |Leche en Polvo    |     12.50      |");
            Console.WriteLine("|  09 |Pasta             |      2.50      |");
            Console.WriteLine("|  10 |Pollo Entero      |     10.00      |");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");

            /*here i was thinkin' making a while loop that ask after the input
            if another item is gonna be purchased, till (next != 0)*/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are only using the `codigo` to find products, why not use a `Dictionary<string, Lista>`?

Comment: You just need to loop through and return the `Lista` that has the `.codigo` you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I would use a List of Listas (sounds a bit weird...) right here. A list allows you to dynamically add, store and later on remove objects of a certain type (e.g. string, int, or Lista here in this example). Also, we can look for an item in a list by specifying criteria.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Lista> products = new List<Lista>();

        products.Add(new Lista() { codigo = 01, precio = 6.00, producto = "aceite mezcla" });
        products.Add(new Lista() { codigo = 02, precio = 2.00, producto = "arroz" });

        //Print out 'products'
        foreach (Lista l in products)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}\t|{1}\t|{1}", l.codigo, l.producto, l.precio));
        }

        int consoleInput;
        if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out consoleInput))
        {
            Lista target = products.Find((lista) => lista.codigo == consoleInput);
            if(traget != null)
                Console.WriteLine(target.codigo + "\t" + target.producto + "\t" + target.precio);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    public struct Lista
    {
        public double precio;
        public string producto;
        public int codigo;
    }
```

What we do here is, first of all, declare an initialize our list, then we add these products to our list (at least I think were talking about some kind of product, its always better to think of a good name for a variable). Then we grab the console's input, and - if its an integer - process it further on. We search tel list for an item with the property codigo == consoleInput, means an Item with the same cardio, as what the user entered into the console. After that, we print it out on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an array. Array have a fixed length, which makes it impossible to add it a variable number of elements and works only if you know the exact number in advance. Use a list instead

```
var v = new List<Lista>();
v.Add(element);
```

Then your newly created array contains only null entries! There are no `Lista` objects inside. You would have to add them like this:

```
v[0] = new Lista { producto = "aceite mezcla", precio = 6.00, codigo = 01 };
```

If you use a list, this becomes

```
v.Add(new Lista { producto = "aceite mezcla", precio = 6.00, codigo = 01 });
```

In both cases (array or list) you can simplyfy the printout like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("| Cod |      Producto    |     Precio     |");
foreach (Lista l in v) {
    Console.WriteLine($"| {l.codigo:00,3} |{l.producto, 18}|{l.precio:n2,-11}     |");
}
```

See also:

- [String Interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/csharp-6#string-interpolation)
- [Composite Formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

Now, to your question: You can use [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx) to search for the product, but first you will have to convert the input of the user which is alwyas a `string` to an `int`.

```
Console.WriteLine("Codigo = ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
int codigo;
if (Int32.TryParse(input, out codigo)) {
    Lista item = v.FirstOrDefault(l => l.codigo == codigo);
    if (item != null) {
        Console.WriteLine($"{item.producto} {item.precio:n2}");
    }
}
```